# JQuery and Custom Tabs using addClass & removeClass

Tags: jquery-ui

So I am pretty new to JQuery and just spent 5 hours getting this working.  If anyone has a better approach please I would love to hear.

*That is my basic question how can it be done cleaner, more streamline?*

What I did was used the minitabs plugin and what the code below will do is toggle custom tabs back and forth.  I needed a way to have the one tab blue and the other gray depending what tab I was on.  What I hit against was **tab1** would stay blue even when I clicked on **tab2**, just was funky until this fixed it.  As you can see it's not the cleanest approach but it works.  I am sure if you want to try this out the minitab plugin can be had here.

```
http://minitabs.googlecode.com/files/jquery.minitabs.js
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#tabs").minitabs('slow', 'fade');

        $("#tab1").click(function()
            {
                var $this = $(this);
                if( $this.is('.removed') ) 
                     {
                       $this.removeClass('removed');
                       $this.addClass('selected');
                       $('#tab2').removeClass('selected');
                       $("#tab2").addClass('removed');
                } else {
                       $('#tab2').removeClass('selected');
             }
    return false;
        });
        $("#tab2").click(function()
            {
                var $this = $(this);
                if( $this.is('.removed') ) 
                  {
                        $this.removeClass('removed');
                        $this.addClass('selected');
                       $("#tab1").removeClass('selected');
                       $("#tab1").addClass('removed');
                } else {
                       $('#tab1').removeClass('selected');

              }
                return false;
        });
   });
```

Body:

```
<div id="tabs"> 
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#quick-links" class="tab-l selected" id="tab1">tab-l</a></li>
            <li><a href="#newsletter-link" class="tab-r removed" id="tab2">tab-r</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="quick-links">
<ul>
  <li>Look at me getting myself all in a frenzy!</li>               
</ul>
        </div>

        <div id="newsletter-link">
  Sometimes it's would be nice if they reported the fun news!
        </div>   

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this briefly, and didn't see any problems with this less-complex setup which  takes advantage of minitabs automatically applying the class "current" to the currently selected tab:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .tabs a {
        background: grey;
    }
    .tabs a.current {
        background: blue;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tabs").minitabs('slow', 'fade');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#quick-links" class="tab-l current" id="tab1">tab-l</a></li>
            <li><a href="#newsletter-link" class="tab-r" id="tab2">tab-r</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="quick-links">
            <ul>
                <li>Look at me getting myself all in a frenzy!</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="newsletter-link">
            Sometimes it's would be nice if they reported the fun news!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

For me that handles the case you describe perfectly.

Comment: I guess I could have done it the easy way, lol!  Thanks that work wonders.